# Export raw "event" data from firebase to big query?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

i have an apps that show event in firebase console and i have done linked project to big query, but in big query only show dataset `firebase_crashlytics` and `firebase_messaging`. How i could retrieving `event` data to big query ?

here are my event

[image: event data]

my dataset in big query

[image: dataset in big query]

Answer (score 0):

Fron the documentation: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en

> Once an app is linked to BigQuery, a corresponding dataset is created
> in the associated BigQuery project upon the first daily export of
> events. Each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a new
> table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is streamed into
> an intraday BigQuery table in real-time. Data prior to linking to
> BigQuery is not available for import.

Apart from that:

- check that the connection is not disabled;
- if you have recently linked, it may take at least one day to view the data on BQ.

Comment: i have done make sure the apps linked to big query (firebase crashlytics, performance monitoring, and firebase messaging). but only dataset firebase crashlytics and firebase messaging that having table, and it is not apps event data.

Comment: When you did it?

Comment: link to big query 10 august but until now the event data still did not deliver to big query, how should i do ?

Comment: Have you checked billing configuration?

Comment: i am check are my project linked to billing account and it was linked, i see on [https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/projects] . that is enough or where i checked other billing configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done the problems, i do :

1. Enable integration to Google Analytics
2. Create dummy apps
3. Upgrade Blaze plan
4. Create big query dataset
5. Set up the export (Enable integration to big query)

full step by step that i follow :
[Enable Big query Export](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/enable-bigquery-export-google-analytics-app-web/#step-1-check-your-google-analytics-app-web-property)